# Need Azure ad identity protection for the end users in my application

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

I want Azure for my application's identity management. Also I require a customer to sign up and become the owner account of my application. And he should send invitations to others. Example consider a university principal sending invitations to his instructors. An instructor sending invitations to his students. This should look like an inverted tree structure. Also my application should have many owner accounts. For example, multiple university principals should have an account in my application. How can I implement this using Azure? Should I use Azure AD B2C or Azure AD B2B?
I need azure only for authentication.

Comment: What qualification process does the sign-up require to promote an account to an admin (to invite others)?

Answer (score 0):

Difference to see to choose between the services is which user (random cunsumer or user from same organization) .

You can make use Azure AD B2B which  is a feature of AzureAD service  if the Application is for organisations and their corporate users.

Azure AD B2C target is to build a directory for consumer applications where users can register themselves with e-mail ID or social providers like Google, FB, MSA, known as Federation Gateway. Azure AD B2C is not targeted at organisation users but consumers.

Both are azure ad identity management services .It depend on who your users are from same organization or random customers that registers themselves.

In both services,user can send invitation to other user  through portal or bulk of users using csv template from portal or powershell.

[image]

First the user need to sign in as  global administrator to assign roles to users and groups.

The user can be given owner role to the app.

You can make more than one member as owner to an application

[image]

**References:**

1. [azure-ad-vs-azure-ad-b2c-vs-azure-ad-b2b -SO reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39271230/azure-ad-vs-azure-ad-b2c-vs-azure-ad-b2b)
2. [add-users](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/external-identities/add-users-information-worker)
3. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/privileged-identity-management/groups-assign-member-owner